# Java WindowsSelectorImpl totalChannels

Tags: java, windows, nio, socketchannel

```
server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
server.connect(address);
```

Any idea why when I inspect `selector` in WindowsSelectorImpl I see `totalChannels = 2` even though I register only one channel?

Comment: I am debugging some code where I am using `select()` but I'm not checking which channel is returned in the selectedKeys. The selector returns but the channel doesn't seem to be in the state I was expecting. I was wondering if there is some "secret" channel that comes along with the selector implementation that makes it impossible to rely on the fact that I only registered 1 channel.

Comment: There can be a secret channel when you have > 63 of them registered, but you're barking up the wrong tree here. If the channel isn't in the state you expect you should publish the code that makes you think so.

Comment: I see. Yes, I will do that if I don't manage to figure out the problem. For now I was just wondering why it seems like (internally) there are 2 channels registered.